# How to read a specific string from text file

Tags: powershell-3.0

I just want to read the bottom line of the file (only bottom line ) and very selective string.

For example: file name is Test.txt and if content would be as below

```
2015/08/22 - disabled and path was //CN=Abhi\, O.T. (TJ),OU=NL,DC=abc,DC=com//
2015/09/12 - disabled and path was //CN=Abhi\, O.T. (TJ),OU=IN,DC=abc,DC=com//
```

then i would like to read the content in between "//" i.e.:

```
CN=Abhi\, O.T. (TJ),OU=IN,DC=abc,DC=com
```

could anyone help me on this

-Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

If // are the last Characters in all the lines, The bellow code will help you.

```
[String]$LastLine=(Get-Content 'C:\StackOverFlow\bottomLine''.txt')[-1]
if($LastLine|Select-String '//' -Quiet)
{
    ($LastLine -split '//')[-1]
}
```

Here,
      The last line in the .txt file is taken using the output from the Get-Content cmdlet and by using the index number as '-1', we get the last value of that array.

Then the in the If statement, It'll check the presence of '//', If found it'll split the string by '//' and again selecting the last value using index '-1'  (assuming '//' is the last value for each line)

Regards,
Prasoon Karunan V